# What is exact xpath for the first childnodes of a node?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a XML code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
            <Label/>
            <Label/>
            <Label/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code, this is represented as a XML Document. The question is in the code that follows:

```
public XmlNodeList GetAllChildrenOfName(XmlNode parent, string childName) 
{
    string xpath = childName;
    //string xpath = "/" + childName;
    //string xpath = "//" + childName;

    return parent.SelectNodes(xpath);
}
```

If I call the method for the grid xml node (`GetAllChildrenOfName(gridNode,"Label")`) from the xml code above, it does not return the expected list of 3 labels for any of the suggested xpath values.

Any guesses, how should the xpath look like?

Thanks

Comment: That's not valid code - you've declared xpath three times. I'd tidy the code sample first.

Comment: Given that your code appears like it should work, yet doesn't, it would be helpful to tell us what GetAllChildrenOfName() *does* return for `xpath = childName`. An empty nodelist? Like Marc, I would assume namespaces might be the reason, but if so we can't see that from the sample you posted. If your XML has any xmlns:foo="bar" attributes, on the Grid or Label elements or any ancestor, let us know about that.

Comment: also, why the "first" in your question title? I don't see anything in your question relevant to wanting the first children as opposed to later children.

Comment: The word "first" is my bad english I guess. "First" means all children in the first level of a parentage tree. About the xmlns imports, I editted the code to see which I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I did not find why the sollution, that works for others, does not work for me, I simply used my own method like this:

```
private List<XmlNode> SelectNamedChildNodes(XmlNode parent, string name)
        {
            List<XmlNode> list = new List<XmlNode>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in parent.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == name) list.Add(node);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

It is possible to work with the result just the same way as with the `XmlNodeList`.

Answer (score 3):

`child::` is the default axis, so if `parent` is the `Grid`, then `parent.SelectNodes("Label")` should work, *assuming* that `Label` is in the default namespace. If you have xml-namespaces you'll need to qualify it by creating a namespace manager:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(parent.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("foo","blah/your/namespace");
return parent.SelectNodes("foo:Label", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml("<Grid><Label /><Label /><Label /></Grid>");
    Response.Write(GetAllChildrenOfName(xDoc.FirstChild, "Label").Count.ToString());
}

public XmlNodeList GetAllChildrenOfName(XmlNode parent, string childName)
{
    string xpath = childName;
    return parent.SelectNodes(xpath);
}
```

And the output was 3.